# Display result using select in mysql procedure with cursor

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a mysql procedure that counts number of activated users in `members` table. I want the procedure to, when done counting, display result stored in variable `num` in table. But I can `select num` only inside the loop, so every iteration new table is displayed, and when I put select after loop, nothing is being displayed.

```
delimiter $$
create procedure users()
begin

declare un varchar(25);
declare num int default 0;
declare idd,act int;

declare c cursor for
select id,username,activated from members;

open c;
l: loop
fetch c into idd,un,act;
if act = 1 then set num = num+1;
end if;
end loop l;

close c;
select num; <---------------
end$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: you must define a continue handler, see here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/42446224/7416478

Comment: @DaniloBustos That was it, thank you.